# Ошибка при переносе Joomla! 3.4

Tags: mysql, база-данных, joomla, mysqli

При переносе Joomla! 3.4 возникла ошибка Database Error: Unable to load Database Driver: mysqli.
Корректно вписал конфиги:
$db
$host
$password
$user

Пробовал создать новую базу и юзера с всеми привилегиями но результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $dbtype = 'mysql'
```

установите значение  в файле configuration.php, пример выше.

Comment: Установил такое значение и получаю другую ошибку Database Error: Unable to load Database Driver: mysql
Может ошибка с самим mysql?

Comment: Тогда убедитесь что присутствуют файлы драйвера. Если нету то загрузите их с оригинального дистрибутива!